# SqlCe sorts automatically but I don't it want my SELECT commands to be sorted

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm having a problem with **Sql Ce** in C#. 
I have a database with ids like that for example 
***sS1 , ss2, ss3 ss4, ss5, ss6 ... ss10 ss1***1 etc... 
and this is the order I have when I display the value with visual studio. 
But if I execute this query for example

```
SELECT SubSectionID FROM Section_SubSection WHERE(SectionID=@SectionID)
```

I get the Ids sorted like this automatically. 
**ss1, ss10, ss11, ss2, ss3** etc...

I can't understand why is this happening. Can someone tell me why ? 
I got 2 different versions of the same application I'm making and in the first one it doesn't have that behavior and in the second one it does. 
I'm also wondering does it have a relation with the fetch order: Backward or Forward. I can't seem to find anything related to that online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not specifying an order, you cannot expect any ordering. Use the ORDER BY clause to have the database engine sort your data.

Comment: Exactly, I don't want it to be sorted it out but it's the case. It is ordered. 

In the database the data input order were s1 s2 s3 ... s10 s11 etc .. but when I do a SELECT on it, I get s1, s10, s11, s2, s3 as an example but I want it to stay s1, s2, s3 .... s10

Comment: I think you are looking for an IDENTITY column

Comment: but  didn't create an identity column because the code is created within c# and this column is not a primary key column also. It's just a property of a road. They just represent the name of a section. My problem is why sql ce is sorting my results while I didn't asked so. worse, I don't get that problem in a old versions of the project.

Comment: if I create an Identity column for nothing, just for the purpose of keeping the input order, I know I can "bypass" the problem, but seriously, I don't see why I should create a column just for that while it use to work without it.

Comment: Well to take care of the problem I created an Identity column to sort the column the way I entered them which take care of the problem but I still don't understand why the problem occurred in the first time.  
Thanks for the idea ErikEJ.